# How do I interpolate variable values in the javascript or typescript string?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interpolation, template-strings

Variables File:

```
export class VariableSettings {

   public static string_value: string = 'vikas/${id}/data';


}
```

Other File.

```
import {VariableSettings} from './variables';


    getData(id:string ){
      console.log(`${VariableSettings.string_value}`, `${id}`); 

      // it prints vikas/${id}/data abcd11123

    }`
```

Now I want the result like that "vikas/abcd11123/data". So how can I inject the id in that string.

Any suggestion regarding the same will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is complicated, but instead of interpolling string why not just pass a function like: `string_value (id) {return \`vikas/${id}/data\`}`. In your case, it needs another treatment like using regex to match ${id}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use interpolated strings you need to use the ``` `` ``` string separator as you do in your second snippet. If you already used a non interpolated string to hold the value of your setting, there is no way you can then interpolate it using the interpolation feature (you could use a regex to perform replacement but that is a bit messy).

The simplest solution is to make the field a function and have `id` as a parameter

```
export class VariableSettings {
    public static USER_BOOKINGS = (id: number) => `vikas/${id}/data`;
}
console.log(`${VariableSettings.USER_BOOKINGS(10)}`);
console.log(VariableSettings.USER_BOOKINGS(10)); // Or no interpolation at call site, not needed anymore if you just need the single value
```

The `USER_BOOKINGS` will now be a function that takes as arguments the parameters needed to construct the string. This way the parameters needed for the strings are clear and type-safe.

Comment: public static string_value: string = (id: string) => `vikas/${id}/data`; It throws error Type '(id: string) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI it's no longer a string, it's a function that returns a string. Remove the `:string` it is not necessary, type will be inferred based on assigned arrow function

Comment: Ok.  I will mark this as an answer. Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
public static string_value: string = 'vikas/id/data';

let re = /id/gi; 
let newstr = `${VariableSettings.USER_BOOKINGS}`.replace(re, `${id}`);
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: I don't want to use any regex pattern for that. I just want to do interpolation

Answer (score 1):

```
     export class VariableSettings {
       id:number;
       public static string_value: string;


    constructor(){
      this.id = 123456
      VariableSettings.string_value = `vikas/${this.id}/data`;
}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(VariableSettings.string_value);
  }
    }
```

Comment: Error:- Cannot find name 'id'.

Comment: Please see my newly updated code below which we commited

Comment: It will not change the id. Also, we are using two variables. That not what I want to use

Comment: If you are not  changing the id then put it directly in the string_value @VIKASKOHLI

Comment: If I am not changing then I will not ask this question. Because then it is a static value and I can directly store like "/vikas/12345/data"

Comment: Then what is the exact problem..@VIKASKOHLI